# Is "I saw you were closing the door." grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality

Can you tell me?

> "I saw you close the door."
>   "I saw you closing the door."

These two are correct, but:

> "I saw you were closing the door."

Is this one correct?

Answer (score 1):

They are all correct and all mean different things.

I saw you close the door. = I saw you when you performed that action.

I saw you closing the door.= closing the door is gerund noun phrase. It refers to the action of closing the door.

I saw you were closing the door [when I entered the room by the other door].

The imperfect tense (was doing, was seeing etc.) is used to describe what is happening when something else happens, or to describe an ongoing activity that has come to and end.

- He was working in Paris when I met him.
- We were having fun then. [at some point in the past]

Comment: _I saw you were closing the door_ is the same as _I saw that you were closing the door_: it has a different structure.

Comment: Those two sentences you gave are the same. The *that" is optional.